# Removing Lone Data Points

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

How can I remove lone data points, without neighbors on a dataframe?

Example of the data, how to remove the highlighted data point

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAPHe.png)

Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very inelegant way.

The `max(0, row-1)` and `max(0, col-1)` when slicing are to deal with cells like `(0, 0)`, where -1 otherwise takes it off the edge and it thinks we're wrapping around.

`if sum(pd.isna(i) for i in neighbours) == len(neighbours) - 1` works because, for example in the case of a 3x3 slice (size 9), if there are 8 NaNs and your current cell is not a NaN, then the function works as intended. But if it's 8 and your current cell is one of the NaNs, changing it to NaN doesn't matter.

```
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (5,5)))
A.iloc[2-1:2+2, 2-1:2+2] = pd.NA
A.iloc[2,2] = 1.92

A.iloc[0,1] = pd.NA
A.iloc[0,3] = pd.NA
A.iloc[1,0] = pd.NA

      0     1     2     3  4
0     7  <NA>     3  <NA>  6
1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  5
2     1  <NA>  1.92  <NA>  2
3     6  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  6
4     9     6     4     9  9
```

```
def change_cell_to_NA_if_lone(df, row, col):
    neighbours = df.values[max(0, row-1):row+2, max(0, col-1):col+2].flatten()
    if sum(pd.isna(i) for i in neighbours) == len(neighbours) - 1:
        df.iloc[row, col] = pd.NA

for r in range(A.shape[0]):
    for c in range(A.shape[1]):
        change_cell_to_NA_if_lone(A, r, c)
```

```
      0     1     2     3  4
0  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  6
1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  5
2     1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  2
3     6  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  6
4     9     6     4     9  9
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How would I update the code, so that it is only effective on rows. I have updated the image on the original post.